# Kubernetes deployment object throws the 405 errors

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I try to make Kubernetes test cluster with Minikube on Windows 10. I use my Spring Boot image which contains Tomcat middleware and Thymeleaf. First I make Pod manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app-boot
  labels:
    deploy: boot-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: boot-app
    image: app:latest  # This image is generated by local docker machine and it works successfully. It contains tomcat and thymeleaf
    imagePullPolicy: Never  
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
    args: ["-t", "-i"]

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-boot-svc
spec:
  selector:
    deploy: boot-app  
  ports:
  - port: 8080 

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: boot.aaa.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: app-boot-svc
              port: 
                number: 8080
```

The above Kubernetes manifest works successfully without errors. Then I change the Pod object to Deployment like below,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: boot-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deploy: boot-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        deploy: boot-app  
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: boot-app
        image: app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        args: ["-t", "-i"]
```

But the ingress hostname throws the errors,

```
[nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

The Spring Boot codes which bring out this issue has only http get method only.

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public void list(@ModelAttribute("pageVO") PageVO vo, Model model) {
....
....
```

However when I use my Spring Boot Pod objects, the ingress hosts throws no errors. In the case of using Deployment objects, the web browser throws the following errors.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405)
```

Is there another option which configure the default web method of Kubernetes pod, service or ingress? If there is, I want to know how to set the default web method of ingress host.

### Update

I set the replicas number of Deployment object to 1, Then no errors are thrown from Minikube. And below codes are the Service codes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-boot-svc
spec:
  selector:
    deploy: boot-app
  ports:
  - port: 8080
```

I am afraid my service object codes would contain some errors. Any idea?

Comment: Does the same error occur when you run this on linux without it being containerized?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am afraid I test this issue on windows 10 only

Comment: So you are running this on Hyper-V and the Springboot and tomcat images are windows images, yes? Then my question remains the same: Does this error occur when your run this on _Windows_ without it being containerized?

Comment: With windows docker machine, I build this docker image and containerize docker container. And I run this spring boot container on localhost and no errors are returned. When I extend this local image on k8s pod, also no errors. I hope this will help your understanding

Comment: @Marco Would you kindly check my Updated Part? I add the service object codes.